Does Delta Lake OSS support archiving data in different S3 storage classes within a single table?
I'm working with Delta Lake OSS and trying to implement data archiving similar to what's described here: Archive Data with Delta Lake.
Goal:
Store some data in cheaper S3 storage (e.g., S3 Glacier).
Keep the rest of the data in regular S3 storage.
Manage everything within a single Delta table registered in the AWS Glue Catalog.
Questions:
Is it possible to achieve this with Delta Lake OSS?
If so, how can I technically implement this archiving strategy?
